# $response = file_get_contents($request) returns false

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get an XML file with an url:

```
$request="http://www.example.com/server.php?q=showphonenumbers";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
```

If I try another request it will show, but somehow this returns false.

`var_dump($response);` shows: string(8334) " False "

The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE CallOverview>
<CallOverview>
<Calls Count="46">
<Call CallType="GeoCall" Customer="this account" StartTime="2013-11-22 18:58:07 (UTC)" Destination="+1...." Duration="00:23:40"/>
<Call CallType="PSTNOut" Customer="this account" StartTime="2013-11-15 16:48:52 (UTC)" Destination="+1...." Duration="00:00:04"/>
.
.
.
</Calls>
<MoreData>False</MoreData>
</CallOverview>
```

Could the last False of `moredata` the only thing that's showing or is the file unreadable?

Comment: It's XML, and your browser is trying to render it. do a `view source` in your browser. `string (8334)` in your vardump should've been a clue that there's "more than meets the eye"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the browser, because you didn't put `echo '<pre>';`, the browser attempting to render the xml as html, thus only `<MoreData>False</MoreData>` is considered as text and shown.

If you view the source or run this through cli, you'll see that your content is there.

You can also use `header("Content-type: text/plain");`.

Comment: You're right! If I click view source I see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's becouse you didn't put `http://` before `www.`.

```
$request="www.example.com/server.php?q=showphonenumbers";
```